# Do J'ba Fofi (Congolese Giant spiders) exist?

Tags: cryptozoology

[It's Something wiki](https://itsmth.fandom.com/wiki/J%27Ba_Fofi) (dedicated to cryptozoology) reports:

> The J'ba Fofi (Baka: "giant spider"), also known as the Congolese Giant Spider is a cryptozoological creature that is said to exist in the Congo, possibly representing a new species of arachnid. It is considered a cryptid and only in recent years has received publicity.
>
> The J'ba Fofi is described as having a brownish body similar to that of a tarantula, with a legspan of four to six feet.

Also in https://pinebarrensinstitute.com/cryptids/2018/8/18/cryptid-profile-jba-fofi

Does this animal exist?

Comment: Note: The OP has rage-quit after having the question edited.

Comment: Checking OP's edit where he/she added "_according to Baka natives_" looks like it was a biassed quiestion. That could alse be a reason of the rage-quit

Comment: Is a creature that is "said to exist" by a site dedicate to cryptozoology even notably claimed to exist?

Answer (score 4):

[As the BBC reports](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20160314-the-worlds-largest-spider-is-the-size-of-a-dinner-plate), a huntsman spider found in Laos with a legspan of about 300mm (about 1 ft) is considered the largest known to science.